# in eclipse mysql database is pinged successful, but program is not pinging

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DBDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            System.out.println("db is pinging.....");

           }catch(Exception e){

           System.out.println("Exception occured");

           }

    }

}
```

O/P
Exception occured

i tested database connection that was pinging but by program i cannot connect to db . please tell me what to do? 
last time when i faced this problem then i delete eclipse and working folder then it was working. but again i faced same problem (this is annoy). thanks.

Comment: Can you provide error logs.

Comment: log please, have you included mysql driver into classpath?

Comment: Rather than just printing out 'Exception occured' call 'e.printStackTrace()' to get more details about the exception.

Comment: @cigno5.5 thanks it worked .but not working with servlet.

Comment: try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            System.out.println("db is pinging.....");

           }catch(Exception e){

           e.printStackTrace();

           }

and then share your log please

Comment: Ok, please replace "System.out.println("Exception occured");" with a stack trace print (e.printStackTrace()) and you're going to understand better the source of the problem. When the problem is understood we'll find a solution